# Return previous screen not working

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have two screens in my app, let's say screen A and screen B. Please see my code below.

screen A -> screen B:

```
  EditProfileFragment contactFragment = new EditProfileFragment();
            android.app.FragmentTransaction contactTransaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            contactTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, contactFragment, GlobalVariable.MyPROFILE_EDIT_FRAGMENT);
            contactTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

            contactTransaction.commit();
```

after saving the record, I want to return to previous screen B -> A:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

But it's not working. Nothing else happens. I've been googling for a few hours but I'm still not able to find any solution.

Comment: I suggest you to use the fragmentsDelegate pattern. And does the replace/popBackStack from an activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not wrong you're trying to return previous fragment. So why don't you just use:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

I edit your code: (User SupportFragment and SupportFragmentManager)

```
  EditProfileFragment contactFragment = new EditProfileFragment();
            FragmentTransaction contactTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            contactTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, contactFragment, GlobalVariable.MyPROFILE_EDIT_FRAGMENT);
            contactTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            contactTransaction.commit();
```

And use when you save record:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: Hi thanks is working now. But why  contactTransaction.add is not working?

Comment: just bit weird that why .add is not working. but is ok . I accept ur answer. thanks